# Can i use date object as key in JSON object javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I recieved strings of dates in my Javascript as keys of JSON object. I want to replace the keys with their Date objects. So i did this.(postdata is the name of JSON object)

```
    for (var key in postdata){
        var temp = postdata[key];
        postdata[parseDate(key)] = temp;
        delete postdata[key];           
    }
```

This is the parseDate function..

```
    function parseDate(input) {
        var parts = input.split('-');
        return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
    }
```

But when i retrieved the keys later and try to sort the keys its not working.

```
    var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
         if (date1 > date2) return 1
        if (date1 < date2) return -1
        return 0
    };
    for (var key in postdata){
        graph_label.push(key)
    }
    graph_label.sort(date_sort_asc)
```

I tried this on list of dates and it worked perfectly. But when retrieved from JSON as keys its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *strings* as property names.

If you try to use a `Date` object, `.toString()` will be called on it automatically giving you a property name such as `"Tue Apr 01 2014 07:27:26 GMT+0100 (BST)"`.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript keys of object always convert to strings so it is not good practice to store Date as key of object. I think it is better to create array of objects.

Here is code: http://jsbin.com/tijamepu/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: You are right :).. I should take another way i guess. Thanks